# JSP Correct way to pass value in input tag

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have doubt in passing java variable in my JSP page, I wanted to know which way is correct or both will work

In my JSP I am doing like this

(1) `<input type="hidden" name="encodedUsername" value= <%= certificateStr %> >`

(2) `<input type="hidden" name="encodedUsername" value="<%= certificateStr %>">`

can someone tell if (1) and (2) both are valid or if any one is incorrect way to pass value

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first one will render to incorrect HTML as the attribute value will not be enclosed in quotes.